# How to write correctly regex pattern for less command

Tags: regex, linux, less-unix

How convert this pattern

```
Some_Word>[\n\t\r].*?[\n\t\r].*?[\n\t\r].*?<symbol>BK<\/symbol>
```

When I'm used this with the **less** command, then I not found nothing.

P.S. I checked [here](https://regex101.com/) that patter with the text and it work correctly:

```
before bla bla<Some_Word>
ssssssssssssssssssss>
dddddddddddddddddddd>
ccccccccccccccccccccc <symbol>BK</symbol>
after bla bla>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. What are you trying to do? Can you rephrase *"to be less recognize his?"*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Some_Word>.*?<symbol>BK<\/symbol>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH2fM4/1)

**Explanation:**
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)

Comment: not working for me:
/Some_Word>.*?<symbol>BK<\/symbol> and 
?Some_Word>.*?<symbol>BK<\/symbol>
found nothing